# why Snowflake changing the order of JSON values when converting into flatten list?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have JSON objects stored in the table and I am trying to write a query to get the first element from that JSON.

Replication Script

```
create table staging.par.test_json (id int, val varchar(2000)); 

insert into staging.par.test_json values (1, '{"list":[{"element":"Plumber"},{"element":"Craft"},{"element":"Plumbing"},{"element":"Electrics"},{"element":"Electrical"},{"element":"Tradesperson"},{"element":"Home services"},{"element":"Housekeepings"},{"element":"Electrical Goods"}]}');
insert into staging.par.test_json values (2,'
  {
    "list": [
      {
        "element": "Wholesale jeweler"
      },
      {
        "element": "Fashion"
      },
      {
        "element": "Industry"
      },
      {
        "element": "Jewelry store"
      },
      {
        "element": "Business service"
      },
      {
        "element": "Corporate office"
      }
    ]
  }');



with cte_get_cats AS
(
select id, 
       val as category_list 
       from staging.par.test_json
),
cats_parse AS
(
  select id,
         parse_json(category_list) as c
  from cte_get_cats
),
distinct_cats as
(
  select id,
         INDEX,
         UPPER(cast(value:element AS varchar)) As c
  from 
      cats_parse,
      LATERAL flatten(INPUT => c:"list")
  order by 1,2 
) ,
cat_array AS
    (
        SELECT  
            id,
            array_agg(DISTINCT c) AS sds_categories
        FROM
            distinct_cats
        GROUP BY 1
    ),
sds_cats AS
( 
         select id,
         cast(sds_categories[0] AS varchar) as sds_primary_category
         from cat_array
)
select * from sds_cats;
```

Values: Categories

```
{"list":[{"element":"Plumber"},{"element":"Craft"},{"element":"Plumbing"},{"element":"Electrics"},{"element":"Electrical"},{"element":"Tradesperson"},{"element":"Home services"},{"element":"Housekeepings"},{"element":"Electrical Goods"}]}
```

Flattening it to a list gives me

```
["Plumber","Craft","Plumbing","Electrics","Electrical","Tradesperson","Home services","Housekeepings","Electrical Goods"]
```

**Issue:**
The order of this is not always same. Snowflake seems to change the ordering sometimes snowflake changes the order as per the alphabet.
How can I make this static. I do not want the order to be changed.

Comment: Can you please clean up your query? What you submitted won't compile, you're missing WITH, using inconsistent names etc (e.g. what is `cats_array`), etc. Ideally, also provide a minimal example with a CREATE TABLE and INSERT statement, and make sure it works in Snowflake before posting here.

Comment: yes will provide a working version of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're using `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
        array_agg(DISTINCT c) AS sds_categories
```

Specifying it like that gives Snowflake no guidelines on how the contents of array should be arranged. You should **not** assume that the arrays will be created in the same order as their input records - it might, but it's not guaranteed. So you probably want to do

```
        array_agg(DISTINCT c) within group (order by index) AS sds_categories
```

But that won't work, as if you use `DISTINCT c`, the value of `index` for each `c` is unknown. Perhaps you don't need `DISTINCT`, then this will work

```
        array_agg(c) within group (order by index) AS sds_categories
```

If you do need `DISTINCT`, you need to somehow associate an `index` with a distinct `c` value. One way is to use a `MIN` function on `index` in the input. Here's a full query

```
with cte_get_cats AS
(
select id, 
       val as category_list 
       from staging.par.test_json
),
cats_parse AS
(
  select id,
         parse_json(category_list) as c
  from cte_get_cats
),
distinct_cats as
(
  select id,
         MIN(INDEX) AS index,
         UPPER(cast(value:element AS varchar)) As c
  from 
      cats_parse,
      LATERAL flatten(INPUT => c:"list")
  group by 1,3 
) ,
cat_array AS
    (
        SELECT  
            id,
            array_agg(c) within group (order by index) AS sds_categories
        FROM
            distinct_cats
        GROUP BY 1
    ),
sds_cats AS
( 
         select id,
         cast(sds_categories[0] AS varchar) as sds_primary_category
         from cat_array
)
select * from cat_array;
```

Comment: The query performance is very slow when using `array_agg(c) within group (order by index) AS sds_categories ` as I have 2 billion rows

Comment: If I put `where index = 0`, i can get the query to run much faster almost 3.2x faster.

Comment: I mean, if you always need element index 0, then sure! But they you don't need array_agg etc - just do `SELECT parse_json(category_list)[0]` :)